# Showing that two knots are equivalent if an invertible linear transformation maps one onto another.

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, proof-writing, knot-theory, knot-invariants

The question is:

Let $K_{1}$,$K_{2}$ be two knots in $\mathbb{R^3}$. Let $T: \mathbb{R^3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^3}$ be an invertible linear transformation such that $T(K_{1}) = K_{2}$. Show that $K_{1} \cong K_{2}$.

**The meaning of $K_{1} \cong K_{2}$, is given below:**

The definition of equivalence of 2 knots according to Richard H. Crowell and Ralph H. Fox, edition 1963, is:

Assume that $K_{1}$,$K_{2}$ are 2 knots in $\mathbb{R^3}$, then they are equivalent , denoted by $K_{1} \cong K_{2}$, iff $\exists f: \mathbb{R^3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^3}$, where $f$ is a homeomorphism and such that $f(K_{1}) = K_{2}.$

**My thoughts:**

I want to find a homeomorphism $f$, such that $f(K_{1}) = K_{2}$. I think the given linear transformation is that homeomorphism, and it is one-one because it is invertible, but I do not know why it should be onto (as the definition of homeomorphism requires the function to be bijection) could anyone explain this for me please?

Also I think that the given linear transformation is bicontinuous because cutting the ropes of the knotes are not allowed, am I correct?

Comment: Hint: Rank-Nullity Theorem. Alternatively, the inverse of the given transformation has domain $\mathbb{R}^3$, hence the transformation has range $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: what about my questions? @quasi

Comment: Yes, since linear transformations are continuous, and since the given linear transformation is invertible, it's a homeomorphism.

Comment: Any linear transformation is continuous? or just the given one?@quasi

Comment: Any linear transformation from $R^n$ to $R^m$ is continuous. If you write out the full form of $f(x_1,...,x_n)$ as an $m$-tuple $(y_1,...,y_m)$, then each of the component functions $y_1,..,y_m$ is just a linear polynomial in the variables $x_1,...,x_n$.

Comment: @quasi Why not an official answer?

Comment: @Paul Frost:  A few short comments seemed more appropriate, in this case.

Comment: And $T^{-1}$ is continuous why? @quasi

Comment: @hopefully: If $T$ is linear and invertible, then $T^{-1}$ is also linear (think about the associated matrices).

Comment: because any matrix is linear  ..... correct?@quasi

Comment: @hopefully: Any linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ can be represented by an $m{\,\times\,}n$ matrix $A$ such that $T(x)=Ax$, and yes, the map $x\mapsto Ax$ from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$ is linear.