# The relation between mirror image and equivalence of two knots.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, linear-transformations, knot-theory, knot-invariants

The question is:

Let $T(x, y, z) = (x, y , z)$ and $K_{1}$,$K_{2}$ are 2 knots such that $T(K_{1}) = K_{2}$. Show that $K_{1} \cong K_{2}$.

**Where $K_{1} \cong K_{2}$ is defined below:**

The definition of equivalence of 2 knots according to Richard H. Crowell and Ralph H. Fox, edition 1963, is:

Assume that $K_{1}$,$K_{2}$ are 2 knots in $\mathbb{R^3}$, then they are equivalent , denoted by $K_{1} \cong K_{2}$, iff $\exists f: \mathbb{R^3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^3}$, where $f$ is a homeomorphism and such that $f(K_{1}) = K_{2}.$

**The hint that was given to me is:**

The solution is an easy consequence of this question:

[Showing that two knots are equivalent if an invertible linear transformation maps one onto another.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3278350/showing-that-two-knots-are-equivalent-if-an-invertible-linear-transformation-map)

But I do not understand how, could anyone clarify this for me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that we know that the linear map $f \colon \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is bounded. Then we get $$\left\|f(v) - f(v')\right\|= \left\|f(v - v')\right\| \leq C\left\|v-v'\right\|$$ for some $C$. Thus $f$ is Lipschitz continuous and therefore also continuous. Therefore it suffices to show that any linear map $f \colon \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is bounded. Let $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and write $v = v_1e_1 + \dots + v_n e_n$ as a linear combination of the standard basis. Then we get $$\left\|f(v)\right\| = \left\|v_1f(e_1) + \dots + v_n f(e_n)\right\| \leq \vert v_1 \vert\left\|f(e_1)\right\| + \dots + \vert v_n \vert \left\| f(e_n)\right\|$$ by the triangle inequality. As any two norms on $\mathbb{R}^n$ are equivalent, there exists some $C$ such that $\vert v_1 \vert + \dots + \vert v_n \vert \leq C \left\| v\right\|$. Thus we get $$\left\| f(v)\right\| \leq \vert v_1 \vert\left\|f(e_1)\right\| + \dots + \vert v_n \vert \left\| f(e_n)\right\|\leq (\vert v_1 \vert + \dots + \vert v_n \vert)D \leq CD \left\| v\right\|,$$
where $D = \text{sup}(\left\|f(e_i)\right\|)$. Thus $f$ is bounded.

This means you can take the invertible linear map as the homeomorphism that you were searching.

Comment: Is the defined linear transformation is correct? or should it be $T(x, y, z) = (x, y, -z)$?

Comment: you mean amphicheiral?

Comment: Yes, that one is correct (the one with the minus).

Comment: But How can we use the given hint?

Comment: And what is the importance of this given linear transformation? I mean the one I mentioned in my first comment.

Comment: I do not understand your answer...... could you provide more details please?

Comment: Could you please look at this question (when you have time)? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3279328/showing-that-amphicheirality-of-2-knots-implies-their-equivalence

Comment: The mirror map is invertible (actually by itself). Therefore you have an invertible linear map (which also means that the inverse is linear (here directly since it is selfinverse)). Now I explained why linear maps $\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ are continuous such that $T$ is a homeomorphism which sends $K_1$ to $K_2$. That is your definition of equivalent knots.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "The mirror map is invertible (actually by itself)."?

Comment: It means $T \circ T = \text{id}$, so $T = T^{-1}$.

Comment: I think by the exercise I mentioned and because the mirror map is invertible the result follows directly ...... correct?

Comment: Yes, you got it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your great effort .....could you please look at this question (if you have time)? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3279328/showing-that-amphicheirality-of-2-knots-implies-their-equivalence