# Showing that amphicheirality of 2 knots implies their equivalence.

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-writing, equivalence-relations, knot-theory, knot-invariants

The question is:

If $K_{1}$,$K_{2}$ are amphicherial knots. Show that $K_{1} \cong K_{2}$.

**The definition of amphicheiral is as follows:**

A knot $K$ is amphicheiral iff there exists an orientation preserving homeomorphism of $\mathbb{R^3}$ onto itself which maps $K$ onto its mirror image.

**The definition of mirror image of a knot $K$ is as follows:**

By the mirror image of a knot $K$ we mean the image of $K$ under the reflection $\mathscr{R}$ defined by $(x, y, z) \rightarrow (x, y, -z).$

**The meaning of $K_{1} \cong K_{2}$, is given below:**

The definition of equivalence of 2 knots according to Richard H. Crowell and Ralph H. Fox, edition 1963, is:

Assume that $K_{1}$,$K_{2}$ are 2 knots in $\mathbb{R^3}$, then they are equivalent , denoted by $K_{1} \cong K_{2}$, iff $\exists f: \mathbb{R^3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^3}$, where $f$ is a homeomorphism and such that $f(K_{1}) = K_{2}.$

**My thoughts:**

By the definition of amphicherality there exists an orientation preserving homeomorphism of $\mathbb{R^3}$ onto itself which maps $K$ (take it to be $K_{1}$) onto its mirror image (take it to be $K_{2}$) and hence the equivalence definition is satisfied and we are done...... am I correct?

**EDIT:**

I think I am incorrect as the given definition of amphicherality deals with only one knot ..... am I correct?

Comment: As you note in the edit, what you have written as your main question is not true as stated.  There are many amphicheiral knots which are not equivalent.

Comment: So what should be the correct title? @N.Owad I think the question means what I have written in the title.

Comment: @N.Owad  could you please look at this question (if you have time)?https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3278615/the-relation-between-mirror-image-and-equivalence-of-two-knots/3278650?noredirect=1#comment6744558_3278650

Comment: @N.Owad so how can I deal with 2 knots?

Comment: Maybe the implication was that $K_2$ is the mirror of an amphicheiral $K_1$, which implies $K_2$ is also amphicheiral. On that reading, you must show an amphicheiral knot is equivalent to its mirror image.

Comment: the question is exactly what is written in the second line@J.G. ..... is the original statement contains something wrong? or just the title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a long comment.  Let $K$ be a knot and $-K$ be its mirror image.  A knot $K$ is said to be amphichieral if it is equivalent to $-K$.  So if you have two knots $K_1$ an $K_2$, they can only be amphichieral if they are already equivalent, but neither need be the mirror image of the other. Often, questions likes these are phrased in terms of their diagrams.

Comment: Is amphichierality an equivalence relation?

Comment: Chirality is a property of a knot.  Not a relation.  A knot is amphicheiral or it is not.  It has nothing to do with another knot.

Comment: you mean if 2 knots are equivalent they will be amphicheiral without needing to be mirror images of each other ...... how do you know this?

Comment: I think if we set $K_{2} = $ the mirror image of $K_{1}$ the question will be correct.

Comment: Yes.  "Let $K$ be an amphicheiral knot and $-K$ be the mirror image.  Show that $K = -K$."  This should be very straight forward.